# Displaying a Dataframe on a plotly plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, plotly

Say I want to display a small one row dataframe on a plot, is this possible?

Example:

```
    buy_hold    coin    lose.max    no_trades   strat_prof  win.max
0   7.406522    DASH    -2.115741   89.0    270.080641  123.46243
```

I want the resulting plot to look like this:
[image: plot]

Comment: Is this MATLAB related? Also, how do you want to display it? It is possible, in infinite different ways. What do you want the plot to look like?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific, like this http://i.imgur.com/dRJM9YI.png

Comment: also bonus question do you know why the colors don't change you change the rgbp tuple on 'double y axis example' ? https://plot.ly/python/multiple-axes/

Comment: That's why I said 'display' not 'plot' in the title

Comment: sorry, it is not clear, how your desired figure is related to the data.

Comment: @IlyaV.Schurov Its not the plot, but the table below the plot what OP wants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: I first suggested using Pandas to plot the table, but it can also be done directly with Matplotlib.

Matplotlib has a method for displaying tables in plots, and it can be customized in many ways, see the documentation [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.table).

Here is a plot that looks quite similar to what you want:

[image]

The code for the plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plot([1, 3], [40, 60])
plot([2, 4], [40, 60])
ylim(37, 60)

columns = ["buy_hold", "coin", "lose.max", "no_trades", "strat_prof", "win.max"]
cell_text = [["7.406522", "DASH", "-2.115741", "89.0", "270.080641", "123.46243"]]

# Add a table at the bottom of the axes
the_table = plt.table(cellText=cell_text,
                      colLabels=columns,
                      colWidths=[.15]*len(columns),
                      loc='lower right')

# Adjust layout to make room for the table:
#plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3)

plt.show()
```